Why does Gradle not recognize Dokka plugin in buildSrc?
EDIT: Question is closed; I no longer require feedback.
I am building a multi-module Gradle project which tries to use buildSrc to define Kotlin classes, properties, functions, etc. that can be used in the build-scripts of each of my modules.
Here is the directory structure of buildSrc:
buildSrc
├── build.gradle.kts
└── src
    └── main
        └── kotlin
            └── dokka
                ├── configureDocumentation.kt
                ├── Directory.kt
                ├── DocumentationManifest.kt
                ├── SourceSet.kt
                ├── TraditionalSourceRoot.kt
                └── VisibilityDocSet.kt

In this case, the library I intend to use is under buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka.
In buildSrc/build.gradle.kts, I included the Dokka plugin under plugins, expecting that would solve the issue:
plugins {
   `kotlin-dsl`
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.8.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "1.7.20"        <---- PLUGIN DEFINITION
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}

Unfortunately, when trying to compile the code under buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka for later use, I get a bunch of unresolved reference errors pertaining to org.jetbrains.dokka:
> Task :buildSrc:compileKotlin FAILED
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/VisibilityDocSet.kt:3:55 Unresolved reference: dokka
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:7:5 Unresolved reference: tasks
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:7:34 Unresolved reference: gradle
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:8:9 Unresolved reference: dokkaSourceSets
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:10:17 Unresolved reference: named
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:11:21 Unresolved reference: sourceRoots
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:11:38 Unresolved reference: file
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:12:21 Unresolved reference: reportUndocumented
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:13:21 Unresolved reference: skipEmptyPackages
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:14:21 Unresolved reference: documentedVisibilities
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:17:17 Unresolved reference: configureEach
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:18:21 Unresolved reference: sourceRoots
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:18:38 Unresolved reference: file
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:19:21 Unresolved reference: reportUndocumented
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:20:21 Unresolved reference: skipEmptyPackages
e: .../buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dokka/configureDocumentation.kt:21:21 Unresolved reference: documentedVisibilities

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 6s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

I am new to using Gradle (especially when it comes to multi-module projects and buildSrc).
Perhaps there is something I don't understand about how buildSrc works or something I am missing when it comes to configuring it properly.

I believe you need to configure buildSrc/build.gradle[.kts] to add the Dokka plugin as a dependency instead of applying the plugin.

@Slaw Yes, you are correct. I’ve been researching for a while, and Dokka is meant to allow you to document code (and it’s specifically a plugin used for configuring certain doc tasks). Obviously it makes no sense to try to use it in actual library code; Gradle and Gradle tasks obviously aren’t accessible there. Sorry for late reply.
